# How to access global variables in panflute (Pandoc filter)

Tags: filter, pandoc

According to [the API documentation](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/code.html),
one is supposed to be able to access global variables through the [`doc` variable](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/code.html#panflute.elements.Doc) somehow.
How though, is not explained.

global variables can be defined in YAML headers:

```
---
title: Document Title
author: Who wrote this
key0: val0

Here starts the document content ...
```

or on the pandoc command line:

```sh
pandoc -V key1=val1 --variable key2=val2 input.md
```

what I tried to access them:

```py
    print("key1=%s" % doc.key1)
    print("key1=%s" % doc.get_metadata('key1', 'NOT-FOUND'))
```

both of which fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach (putting the variable in the document) failed because the YAML block isn't closed, so the block is not read as metadata but as normal Markdown. Adding a closing `---` line after the metadata should fix that.

```
---
title: Document Title
author: Who wrote this
key0: val0
---

Here starts the document content ...
```

---

To see why the command line version failed, one has to look at the distinction pandoc makes between *template variables* and *metadata*. The [doc for `-M`/`--metadata`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--metadata) says:

> Like `--variable`, `--metadata` causes template variables to be set. But unlike `--variable`, `--metadata` affects the metadata of the underlying document (which is accessible from filters and may be printed in some output formats) and metadata values will be escaped when inserted into the template.

Therefore, using `-M` instead of `-V` should solve your problem.

Comment: so the solution for me is: `pandoc ... -M key1=val1 ...` on the cmd-line and then in the filter `doc.get_metadata('key1', 'NOT-FOUND')`. works! thank you! :-)